# ie display:none bug

Tags: html, css

In ie9 I've noticed that `display: none` doesn't seem to work in the following context:

```
<span class="commentsList" id="viewComments-<?php echo $row->idwallPosts; ?>" style="width: 104%; display: none"></span>
```

Does anybody know how to fix this bug?

Comment: 1) why should it not work 2) width on inline-elements has no effect. 3) maybe your id-attribute is broken. Can you perhaps prepare a http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: By "doesn't seem to work", I presume you mean it isn't disappearing, and is still visible on screen? And I presume in the "real" code, the `<span>` has some contents? Can you provide an example of your code where it "does seem to work"?

Comment: Your `span` is empty already so perhaps you can explain more about what "doesn't work" means, and put up a working demo someplace.

Comment: Yes... a jsfiddle would take too long because i don't have static data. but here is the pastebin code: http://pastebin.com/YQyL9Ue4

Comment: it works just fine in chrome and firefox though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You propably set up a rule in CSS that is linked to this object's class/id and overwrites your "display:none;" rule. Can't you just give us a link to your website?

Comment: I went ahead and posted in the jQuery forum. Apparently I forgot to close a div.... which ie doesn't like those kinds of things.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `position:realtive` in your class using `display:none`